# Distributed architecture: kafka, Swarm, others

Tags: architecture, apache-kafka, docker-swarm

I am looking for tips about best architectural organization for a distributed system with the following characteristics:

- On one or more computers will be made available a series of CODED files every minute (about 100 files per minute or 1Gb / min)
- It is necessary to process these files in a cluster to decode them. Each file generates rows in a few tables. There is more than one type of encoding.
- Each file must be processed only once
- These table rows need to be inserted into a database
- The database is distributed and is already available in a cloud.

---

So far, I'm evaluating two possibilities:

- Use docker swarm to process the encoded files and insert the data into the database.

  - Drawback: time spent to insert data in the database is greater than if you used an accumulator later to perform bulk insert. Waste processing resources waiting for insert)
- Use Apache Kafka to connect to all hosts serving files, put them in a stream or batch, and process them. Subsequently, throw the records in an output stream to insert into the database.

  - Drawback: Difficulties of scaling the Kafka cluster, due to the large number of topics vs. the different types of processing for decoded the files vs. file processing requirement of exactly once

Comment: "files in a cluster of one or more computers"... Sounds like you need a DFS, not necessarily a streaming solution or container orchestrator. Also, Docker Swarm would typically be used in conjunction with Kafka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swarm just organizes applications in containers across multiple hosts. I don't see how it relates to your application architecture. If you follow [12factor.net](https://12factor.net/) ideas for designing a distributed system, any container orchestrator will work.